# Standardized coefficients in R for lasso regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

Is there a way to get a list of the standardized coefficients for lasso regression in R? Following cross validation, I have identified the optimal lambda and can then obtain the coefficients appropriate for unscaled data using the predict function. I need the exact same model - i.e. the same coefficients must appear to be non-zero - but the lambda used for the unscaled data makes little sense when running lasso regression on scaled data.

Comment: Can you post the code and the results that are behind this question?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the scaled coefficients for a given `s` from the elastic net (set lambda to 0 to turn off the L2 penalty):

```
predict( model, newx=xmat, s=s, mode="fraction", type="coefficients" )
```